# Polygon infowindows in Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmap4rails to draw a bunch of fairly complicated polygons that serve as district boundaries. I've got two things i would like help with:

Firstly, I want to associate an info window on click with these polygons. This is an example of my use-case: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays

I've tried registering a click event handler in the gmap's callback but it doesn't work and I don't think it's the right approach.

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() 
{
        console.log("'sup");
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
        ({
            content: 'you clicked me!',
            suppressMapPan:true
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.polygons[0], 'click', function() 
        {
            console.log("the click event fired");
            infowindow.open(map, Gmaps.map.polygons[0]);
        });

}
```

Secondly, I'd like to be able to change the fill-color of these polygons via jquery on some user-events (user clicks a checkbox for example). How would I go about that using the gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your method with:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() 
{
    console.log("'sup");
    Gmaps.map.polygons[0].infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
    ({
        content: 'you clicked me!'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.polygons[0].serviceObject, 'click', function(event) 
    {
        console.log("the click event fired");
        infowindow = Gmaps.map.polygons[0].infowindow;
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map);
    });

}
```

And change [this gem's js line](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L219) to put true instead of false. I did set to false since I didn't like the cursor change. Anyway it should be in configuration options. Please create an issue on github so that I remember to fix it.