# Gmaps4Rails and Custom/Nested Points Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have been using gmaps4 rails to build out a site and the gem is a super addition to my project. I am having some trouble however, with nested models and polygons.

I too would like to do something like this:
[Gmaps4rails custom info window with javascript content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170883/polygon-infowindows-in-gmaps4rails)

Models:

```
  class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_gmappable

    has_many :points, :as => :pointable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :points

    def self.create_with_points(name, points)
      zone = Zone.create(:name => name)
      points.map { |point| zone.points.create(:latitude => point[0],
                                              :longitude => point[1]) }
      zone
    end

    def as_polygon_data
      points.collect { |point| { "lat" => point.latitude.to_f,
                                 "lng" => point.longitude.to_f,
                                 "strokeColor" => "#EBAC2A",
                                 "strokeOpacity" => 0.65,
                                 "strokeWeight" => 2,
                                 "fillColor" => "#606F81",
                                 "fillOpacity" => 0.4
                               } }
    end

    def self.all_as_polygon_data
      Zone.all.collect { |zone| zone.as_polygon_data }
    end
  end

  class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pointable, :polymorphic => :true
    acts_as_gmappable
  end
```

To invoke the Zone in the controller I have to call it with to_json instead of to_gmaps4rails:

```
@polygon_json = Zone.all_as_polygon_data.to_json
```

The polygons render on the map perfectly, but I can't add an info window to them. I tried the click event callback in the above-mentioned post, but it did not work for me.

I would also like to know how I can get a handle to these polygons so I can hide them using a checkbox.

Thank you for your time. Hopefully I have provided enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`but it did not work for me` is not a very useful statement.

I can't know what's your problem: do you have any js error?

You can use the whole google js api, the gem is not a brake, it's just a wrapper.

If you want to interact with polygons:

- the data you pass in the view are stored in the array of objects: `Gmaps.map.polygons`
- on page load, the google's polygons are created and are stored in an object I call `serviceObject`.

To sum up, `Gmaps.map.polygons[0].serviceObject` is a google polygon object you can interact with freely.

To be sure the google's object are created, insert your custom methods in the gmaps4rails js callback.

Comment: I realized afterward that I didn't really give enough information for that question, but was away for a a few days and couldn't get back to it. (I appreciate the time you took to respond). When I wrote the original question I was just getting started with trying to implement the clickable polygons but I have since found more information: when I inspect the polygon elements in Firefox it shows that they are not clickable, but the odd thing is when I run it locally it doesn't work but when I deploy it, it works! (I have observed this behaviour in both Firefox and Safari)

Comment: I also edited the gmaps4rails.base.js to add the clickable property to the polygons.

Comment: After installing Passenger and setting up Apache locally (on Mac), the polygons and info windows work.